# How to change the "card" in a span tag - Vue.JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, local-storage

If the "const local (const local = localStorage.getItem("key");" is equal to "name_jp", then change the "card.name_en" to "card.name_jp" which is inside the span tag. How can I do this effectively and correctly?

***Sorry for my bad English

```
    <div class="b-card" v-for="card in list" :key="card.id">
        <span class="span" id="name">
          <span class="span2">+</span> {{ card.name_en }}</span>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { lan } from "@/modules/languages";
import useCards from "@/modules/geral";

export default {
  setup() {
    const cards = useCards();
    const list = computed(() => cards.state.details);
    const local = localStorage.getItem("key");

    return {
      list,
      lan,
      local,
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add computed getter for this field:

```
setup() {
  const cards = useCards();
  const list = computed(() => cards.state.details);
  const local = localStorage.getItem("key");

  const localizedName = computed(() => (card) => {
    if (local === 'jp') {
      return card.name_jp
    } else {
      return card.name_en
    }
  })

  return {
    list,
    lan,
    local,
    localizedName,
  };
}
```

And use it as:

```html
<span class="span2">+</span> {{ localizedName(card) }}</span>
```

Note that changing the value in `localStorage` does not redraw the component. The `localStorage.getItem('key')` is not a reactive property; therefore, each change must be accompanied by a redrawing of the component. Alternatively, you can use, for example, the [`useLocalStorage`](https://vueuse.org/core/uselocalstorage/#uselocalstorage) from the [`vueuse`](https://vueuse.org/). This will help make the `local` values reactive:

```
setup() {
  const cards = useCards();
  const list = computed(() => cards.state.details);
  const local = useLocalStorage("key");

  const localizedName = computed(() => (card) => {
    if (local.value === 'jp') {
      return card.name_jp
    } else {
      return card.name_en
    }
  })

  return {
    list,
    lan,
    local,
    localizedName,
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked with an objt. But, what if I need to change more than one at the same time?